# Old Dell Dimension 8200 running windows XP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-xp, dell-dimension

Hi everyone I am running Windows XP on an old Dell Dimension 8200 and I made a bootable version of Ubuntu 12.04.2 on a flash drive however when i'm in the bios there is no option to boot from usb. Plus the CD drive doesn't work. I was wondering why this is? I looked it up online and it says its because the computer has 1.1 flash and the flash drive is probably 2.0. All I want to do is run Ubuntu live from the usb and install it while wiping the hard drive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The 8200 does not have usb 2.0, and does not support booting from usb

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/p/19337400/19715801.aspx#19715801

Your best option will be to burn ubuntu to a cd rom.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough that the PC supports USB. The BIOS too should support booting from USB devices. Boot from USB is common in new PCs but not in old PCs.

I think the easiest thing to do is replace the CD drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [Plop Boot Manager v5.0](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) to support boot from USB for old mainboard which BIOS not support boot from USB. I tested in many old mainboard and not face a problem.

You simply run software in windows XP and reboot your PC

Comment: Would I install that on the old computer or on the USB flash drive? And thank you!

Comment: yes, you can install window 7 on the usb after you make a install usb of window 7, or using usb to boot rescure usb :)